# Scrolling with Mouse-down & Space?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsscrollview, nsevent, nsapplication

Is there any sample code or article/guide suggesting how to best implement a click+scroll feature as common in apps like Adobe XYZ, Pixelmator, ..:

> **The user clicks in a view while holding down the Space key to scroll the view**

Should we just move the containing scroll view every time the mouse moves by the delta amount since the previous mouse moved event?

Is there any built-in functionality in `NSScrollView` that we can hook up to in order to perform the click-&-drag scrolling?

Or should we simulate clicking&dragging the scrollbar via the `NSScroller` APIs?

Any hints appreciated!

Not looking for sample code to copy&paste here, more what's the best/most compatible/least code strategy!